# Create multiple dictionaries from a dictionary containing lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that contains lists. I want to create multiple dictionaries from it.

The original is `{'user': ['BEBR', 'FRPA', 'GEMU'], 'udp': ['COLT_BE_8845-udp', 'COLT_FR_8845-udp', 'COLT_DE_8845-udp']}`

and I want something like this

```
[{'user': 'BEBR', 'udp': 'COLT_BE_8845-udp'},
{'user': 'FRPA', 'udp': 'COLT_FR_8845-udp'},
{'user': 'GEMU', 'udp': 'COLT_DE_8845-udp'},
....]
```

i have a sandbox [here](https://repl.it/@louis_philippedescamps/dictionary)

Comment: Do you want to zip the lists together, so your result would be three dictionaries, or do you want the product, where your result would be nine dictionaries?

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
res = [{'user':user,'udp':udp} for user, udp in zip(*d.values())]
```

where `d` is your original dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
result = []
for user, udp in zip(original['user'], original['udp']):
    result.append({'user': user, 'udp':udp})
```

This would return a list of dictionaries, as in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict` with `zip`:

```
d = {'user': ['BEBR', 'FRPA', 'GEMU'], 'udp': ['COLT_BE_8845-udp', 'COLT_FR_8845-udp', 'COLT_DE_8845-udp']}
result = [dict(j) for j in zip(*[[(a, i) for i in b] for a, b in d.items()])]
```

Output:

```
[{'user': 'BEBR', 'udp': 'COLT_BE_8845-udp'}, {'user': 'FRPA', 'udp': 'COLT_FR_8845-udp'}, {'user': 'GEMU', 'udp': 'COLT_DE_8845-udp'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# finds the list in the csvfile dictionary with the key "user"
# the program uses this value to define the length of all list key values in the dictionary
listlength = len(csvfile["user"])

# extract list of keys e.g. user, udp
keys = [key for key in csvfile]

main_list = []
for x in range(listlength):
 sub_dictionary = {}
 for key in keys:
   sub_dictionary[key] = csvfile[key][x]
 main_list.append(sub_dictionary)
print(main_list)
```

or the equivalent

```
csvdict = [{key: csvfile[key][value] for key in [key for key in csvfile]} for value in range(len(csvfile["user"]))]
```